# Same plot in two different output images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new in both python and opencv and trying to develop a simple object tracking GUI by using opencv tracking API. I am using my webcam to test it. My purpose is selecting the target object in the current frame. For this, I plot a rectangle in the center of the window and select the target object with reference to the rectangle. Since the rectangular shape may fail the tracking operation I want to select the target object from the original frame. In the code I create two different frames which are called rawInp and outImage. rawInp is the input video. outImage is the final outcome and I want all the shapes are plotted in this image. I use an external function to plot the rectangle. I show also the rawInp to check it. However, I see the rectangular shape also in this output. How is it possible and how can I solve this problem? Also, how can I use only rawInp variable for both operations? Because copying the same the same variable is not a good way to handle. I am adding the related part of my code but if you want to see the whole code I can add. Thank you in advance for any of your answers.

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():  print ("Could not open video") ,sys.exit()
ok, frame = cap.read(0)
height, width, channels = frame.shape
upper_left = (3*int(width/8), 3*int(height/8))
bottom_right = (5*int(width/8), 5*int(height/8))
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))

class trackingApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(trackingApp,self).__init__()
        loadUi('tracking_ui.ui',self)

        self.rawInp = None
        self.outImage = None
        self.stBtclk = False
        self.trckBtclk = False
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_webcam)
        self.trackingButton.clicked.connect(self.tracking_clicked)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start_webcam(self):
        self.stBtclk = True
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,620)

        self.timer=QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(5)

    def update_frame(self):
        ret, self.rawInp = self.capture.read()
        self.rawInp = cv2.flip(self.rawInp,1)
        self.rawInp = cv2.cvtColor(self.rawInp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        self.rawInp = clahe.apply(self.rawInp)
        self.rawInp = cv2.cvtColor(self.rawInp, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        self.outImage = self.rawInp       
        if self.trckBtclk: self.tracker_update()        
        self.displayImage(self.outImage,1)

    def plotCenter(self, outImage):    
        cv2.rectangle(outImage, upper_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)     
        # Plot the central horizontal and vertical lines
        cv2.line(outImage,(50,int(height/2)),(width-50,int(height/2)),(0,255,0),1)
        cv2.line(outImage,(int(width/2),50),(int(width/2),height-50),(0,255,0),1)
        cv2.imshow('rawInp',self.rawInp)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def tracking_clicked(self):
        if self.stBtclk:
            self.trckBtclk = True
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
            bbox = (3*int(width/8), 3*int(height/8), 2*int(width/8), 2*int(height/8))
            self.tracker.init(self.rawInp, bbox)            

            marker=self.rawInp[3*int(height/8):5*int(height/8), 3*int(width/8):5*int(width/8)]
            self.surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(500)
            kp, des = self.surf.detectAndCompute(marker,None)
            marker = cv2.drawKeypoints(marker,kp,None,(0,0,255),4)
            cv2.imshow("marker", marker)
        else: pass

    def tracker_update(self):
        ok, bbox = self.tracker.update(self.outImage)
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(self.outImage, p1, p2, (0,255,255), 2, 1)
            kp, des = self.surf.detectAndCompute(self.outImage,None)
#            self.outImage = cv2.drawKeypoints(self.outImage,kp,None,(0,0,255),4)
            cv2.putText(self.outImage, "Tracking", (5,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,255,0),2)
        else:
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(self.outImage, "Tracking failure detected", (5,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

    def displayImage(self, outImage, window):
        self.plotCenter(self.outImage)
        qformat=QImage.Format_Indexed8 
        if len(outImage.shape)==3: #[0]=rows, [1]=columns, [2]=channels
            if(outImage.shape[2])==4:
                qformat=QImage.Format_RGBA8888
            else:
                qformat=QImage.Format_RGB888
        outImg=QImage(outImage,outImage.shape[1],outImage.shape[0],outImage.strides[0],qformat)
        outImg=outImg.rgbSwapped() #BRG>>RGB 
        if window==1:               
            self.trackingScreen.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(outImg))
            self.trackingScreen.setScaledContents(True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    window = trackingApp()
    window.show()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

And here is an example screenshot:

The first window is showing the ui and final output while the second one, named "rawInp", is showing the unprocessed input video. I do not expect to see the green rectangle in second window

[image]

Comment: the provided code does nothing unless you call it somewhere. please share more code.

Comment: not sure about your code, but openCV does not deep copy images automatically, so probably you are just editing the original image instead of creating a new output image.

Comment: thanks for the answers. i did not know that openCV does not deep copy images automatically. i found the solution for this. but how about using only one image variable? can i use the same variable to show both original input and the processed one or do i have to copy it?

Comment: you can use the same variable if you render/show/display the image before manipulating it. But you can't automatically undo changes.